# How does Credit Karma calculate the credit report score?

Tags: united-states, credit-score

I signed up for Credit Karma awhile back and I noticed that they are able to run an inquiry just about any time that I hit "update".

- How do they do that, since my understanding is you are only allowed 1
  free inquiry per year?
- Does their inquiry count as a hard hit or a soft hit?
- Will having them monitor my credit score and open accounts negatively affect my credit
  score?
- Is the score that they display just an approximation of the FICO score?

Thanks,

Eric

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- They have a relationship with Transunion.
- Soft. No record of the credit pull on your report.
- No
- It's supplied by one of the three large scoring agencies. There is no one FICO score, each of the big three will differ a bit.

Comment: It should also be noted for #4 that you *are not* getting your FICO score from Credit Karma, it is TransUnion's "TransRisk" score (and your [VantageScore](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vantagescore))

Comment: True. For what it's worth, when I last refinanced in December, my 3 scores varied 50 points high to low and karma was in the middle nearly dead average of the three.